# Minecraft 1.6.2 Cannot Craft Drill or Chainsaw

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-industrialcraft

I cannot seem to craft the drill or chainsaw using the recipes found on the wiki

http://wiki.industrial-craft.net/index.php?title=Chainsaw

I am using vers. 2.0.376 on minecraft 1.6.2

I think they may have replaced the refined iron with other things but ive tried iron plates and iron casing to no avail.

Help would be much appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 1):

The IC2 wiki is not up to date with the experimental versions (which you happen to be using). The recipes for the experimental version can be found on [this page](http://wiki.industrial-craft.net/index.php?title=Recipes_and_Resources) of the IC2 wiki. The recipes are a little more complicated in the experimental versions now, though, and require several steps.

[Not Enough Items (NEI)](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/909223-164-smp-chickenbones-mods/) has most of the IC2 recipes up-to-date (with some exceptions). I recommend installing it to help lookup recipes. In addition to NEI, you will also need [NEI plugins](https://bitbucket.org/mistaqur/nei_plugins/wiki/Home) to be able to look up recipes from many mods, including IC2.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using only IC2? Do you have NEI installed? You can check the recipe in the game using NEI to see if the recipe you are using is valid, or requires modified\other items.

Comment: yep only using IC2, no I did not install NEI, I will do that right now. Thank you